# HTTPS Problem in Facebook

Tags: https

My Facebook format changed because of HTTPS. What should I do? If I’m trying to uncheck –*Browse Facebook on a secure connection (HTTPS) when possible*, it won’t save, the button cannot be clicked. What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

About 6 months ago Facebook started requiring SSL for pages/apps. It was clearly announced to app owners.

You'll need to get an SSL certificate for your site - I recommend [DigiCert](http://www.digicert.com)